# Validate Custom Post Type fields

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm developing a plugin, in which the administrator has the ability to add and remove ZIP codes on the backend. I found that the best way to do this is by creating a custom post type named zip_code with only a title being supported , as that functionality is already built-in to Wordpress.

What I'm having trouble with is validating the title, as it must be a valid ZIP code to avoid errors on the front end.

I've added the following action hooks:

```
    // Action hook to intercept Wordpress' default post saving function and redirect to ours
    add_action('save_post', 'zip_code_save');

    $validator = new Validator();
    // Called after the redirect
    add_action('admin_head-post.php', array($validator, 'add_plugin_notice'));
```

zip_code_save function:

```
public function zip_code_save() {

    global $post;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    if (isset($_POST['post_type']) && $_POST['post_type'] == 'zip_code') {

        $validator = new Validator();

        if (!$validator->validate(get_the_title($post->ID))) {

            $validator->update_option(1);
            return false;
        } else {
            update_post_meta(
                $post->ID,
                'zip_code', get_the_title($post->ID));
        }

    }
}
```

And finally this is my Validator class:

```
class Validator { 
    //This for your your admin_notices hook
    function show_error() {
        echo '<div class="error">
       <p>The ZIP Code entered is not valid. <b>Note</b>: only US ZIP codes are accepted.</p>
       </div>';
    }

    //update option when admin_notices is needed or not
    function update_option($val) {
        update_option('display_my_admin_message', $val);
    }

    //function to use for your admin notice
    function add_plugin_notice() {
        if (get_option('display_my_admin_message') == 1) {
            // check whether to display the message
            add_action('admin_notices', array(&$this, 'show_error'));
            // turn off the message
            update_option('display_my_admin_message', 0);
        }
    }

    function validate($input) {

        $zip = (isset($input) && !empty($input)) ? sanitize_text_field($input) : '';

        if ( !preg_match( '/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/', $zip  ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

The above code successfully outputs an error message if the entered ZIP is not valid, however regardless of the error, it does publish the post. Is there a way to block the publishing of the post if the title is not valid?

Also, is there a way to prevent WP of creating drafts automatically? Since there is so little data, it's really irrelevant here, and more a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a post is a draft or published is defined by the post status, not any of the meta fields, so you'll have to hook into `wp_insert_post_data` and force the `post_status` to draft if anything in your form is invalid:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data ) {
    if ( $data['post_type'] != 'zip_code' )
        return $data;

    // Validate your nonces and $_POST fields here
    if ( ! $valid ) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'draft'; // Force draft
    }
});
```

Also note that `wp_insert_post_data` runs before `save_post`, so you'll have to validate again and save the meta fields in `save_post` just like you're already doing.

I would also recommend not using options for admin notice triggers. They're global for all users, and they're autoloaded by default every time and everywhere. Use the `usermeta` table instead by using `set_user_setting()` and then `get_user_setting()`.

Hope that helps!